# How can I know what percentage is covered by my tests?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I want to know how much of my project is covered by my tests, and I am currently trying to use jest to do so.

This is my `jest.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
  verbose: true,
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.vue$': 'vue-jest',
  },
  jest: {
    coverageThreshold: {
      global: {
        branches: 50,
        functions: 50,
        lines: 50,
        statements: 50,
      },
      './src/components/': {
        branches: 40,
        statements: 40,
      },
      './src/reducers/**/*.js': {
        statements: 90,
      },
      './src/api/very-important-module.js': {
        branches: 100,
        functions: 100,
        lines: 100,
        statements: 100,
      },
    },
  },
}
```

But when I tried to run the command `jest --coverage --coverageReporters="json-summary"`

I get the error: `bash: jest: command not found`
How do I solve this error?

my devDependecies are:

```
 "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.0.0",
    "jest": "^27.5.0",
    "jest-cli": "^27.5.0",
```

Comment: If you're seeing `jest command not found` it simply means you haven't added `jest` to your project. Run `yarn install jest -D`. Or `npm i jest -D`. After you add it, you'll see the coverage in console (or saved to your file, depending on what command you run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is

> bash: jest: command not found

Which means jest isn't added to your project/installed. Install it with: `npm install --save-dev jest`.

[More information about jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started)